# pdflatex fails with `system returned with code 1` when using minted

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm trying to use minted in my LaTeX document, but I keep getting `system returned with code 1` without any further details (see log below) during the compilation.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{python}
  print("Hello")
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Command used for compilation: `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`

[Log output](https://pastebin.com/gDqTiYuM)

I've tried:

- Minimizing the example as far as possible
- Compiling in different folder
- Compiling in clean folder
- Compiling on different drive

I don't really know where to go from here as about 2 hours of googling hasn't yielded any results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The flag is called `shell-escape` not `escape-shell`

Comment: Right, thanks. That's what I meant to write. Updated the post.